# Prevent line break before \footnote

Tags: line-breaking, footnotes

How can I prevent that the number of a footnote is placed on a new line?

[image]

I am using this code:

```
erfüllen und nicht von den Erlöschens-\footnote{The text of the footnote.}
oder Ausschlussgründen\footnote{Text.} der IRO-Verfassung erfasst werden.
```

Comment: Welcome, guess: `Erlöschens"-\footnote`

Comment: Do you use the `babel` package? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I am using `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you. Unfortunately the problem remains.

Comment: You already got two answers, but a minimal working exampple would be needed to reliably answer your question. That is true for almost all LaTeX questions.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Agree, I did some guesswork in terms of the packages he is using, seeing the German language. The complete parapgraph text would also been helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packaging the hyphen into an `\mbox` works for me:

```
erfüllen und nicht von den Erlöschens\mbox{-}\footnote{The text of the footnote.}
oder Ausschlussgründen\footnote{Text.} der IRO-Verfassung erfasst werden.
```

(thanks @barbara beeton)

Comment: it should suffice to put only the hyphen in the `\mbox`.

Comment: @barbara beeton True, thanks, and I have edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution: Load the `amsmath` package (which you may already be doing anyway) and use the `\nobreakdash` macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}         % for '\nobreakdash' macro
\setlength\textwidth{5.5cm}  % just for this example
\begin{document}

\noindent
erfüllen und nicht von den Erlöschens-\footnote{Text}
oder Ausschlussgründen\footnote{Text} der IRO-Verfassung erfasst werden.

\bigskip\noindent
erfüllen und nicht von den Erlöschens\nobreakdash-\footnote{Text}
oder Ausschlussgründen\footnote{Text} der IRO-Verfassung erfasst werden.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since I am not using the `amsmath` package I accepted @vaettchen's answer that does not require the use of an additional package.

Comment: @Jonas - What's your reason for not wanting to load one additional package?

Comment: I do not know if it makes sense to load an additional package which I do not need for other things when I can achieve the desired result without using the package?

Comment: @jonas - It would have been really helpful if you had posted a full minimal working example and had mentioned which packages you use and which ones you do *not* want to use.

Comment: I am sorry. I will keep this in mind for further questions.

Comment: @Jonas - No lasting harm done. :-) As in other walks of life, the more time one takes to ask well-thought-out questions, the more likely one is on this site to get relevant and helpful answers...